# ionic 3, lazy-loading tabs components

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to create a ionic 3 tabs app with lazy loading without importing the components .

in my app.component.ts

```
 rootPage:string = "Tabs";
```

in tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs>
<ion-tab [root]="Favorites" tabTitle="fav" tabIcon="star"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="libaray" tabTitle="Library" tabIcon="book"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

in Favorites.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Favorites } from './favorites';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Favorites,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(Favorites),
  ],
  exports: [
    Favorites
  ]
})
export class FavoritesModule {}
```

so far , the tabs page loads successfully but no view (blank page) .
i think the problem that i'm using [root] attribute with lazy loading !
how to fix that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/).

```
<ion-tab [root]="Favorites" tabTitle="fav" tabIcon="star"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="libaray" tabTitle="Library" tabIcon="book"></ion-tab>
```

Here `libaray` and `Favorites` need to be variables of the component.

In your component try setting string equivalent of the ionic page to the variables in **Tabs.ts**:

```
export class Tabs{
 Favorites:any='Favorites';
 libaray:any = 'libaray'; //assuming you tried to give the page class name to `root`.
}
```

**Note**: Be sure ***not*** to import your lazy loaded pages anywhere other than within the page module.

Comment: yeah, for more info you can check this github issue https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/11323

Comment: May this needs to go into documentation. I don't see this info on official docs.

Comment: @ParagGhadge thanks. Not sure what you mean. Might I suggest you raise an issue in Github for updated docs?

Answer (score -1):

Ensure at Tabs.html you include `[root]="FavoritesRoot"` as indicated below

```
<ion-tabs>
<ion-tab [root]="FavoritesRoot" tabTitle="fav" tabIcon="star"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="libarayRoot" tabTitle="Library" tabIcon="book"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```